# Escape operators <,>,= in MINIFS,MAXIFS etc. formula criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Say I have the following values: 
[image]

And I want to use a formula to identify the minimum value, where the label = "<25th"

Normally, I would write this as:

```
=MINIFS(B2:B13,A2:A13,"<25th")
```

The problem is excel is taking the leading "<" as part of the formula, so is actually looking for values less than "25th", bearing in mind it's a string not numeric, so it returns 1

I want it to return the actual minimum for "<25th", which should be 9.

Microsoft documentation https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/minifs-function-6ca1ddaa-079b-4e74-80cc-72eef32e6599 doesn't cover escaping operators, and I can't see anything elsewhere on it either.

A work around is to put "=" in front of the criteria, which seems to work. Is this a sensible solution, or could that also have undesirable consequences for larger data sets / criteria? Is there a proper way of escaping these reliably?

Comment: Use `"=<25th"` as the criterion

Comment: Hi Rory - I tried that and it did work, but was unsure whether that is safe - i.e. wont throw up any undesirable matches elsewhere?

Comment: I've never seen it cause an issue. You could also use `SUMPRODUCT` instead.

Comment: Great - thanks for your help